# QT using QML textedit and/or textarea, how to map which index in textedit.text is mapped to formatted text

Tags: qt, qml

In QML TextEdit or TextArea, we can format or style a text either HTML or Markdown, the non-formatted text can be accessed by TextArea.text but the formatted text can be accessed by getFormattedText().

I want to know how to get which index in the non-formatted text is equivalent for the formatted text, this is important when say, If I select a text in the formatted view, I want to change its markdown in the non-formatted view. There seems to not have a method for this.

example, in formatted view a string with "1\n2\n3\n4" which means every line there is a text, is equivalent to "1\n\n2\n\n3\n\n" or a bold text like in formatted "text" is equivalent to "**text**" in non formatted.

So if I have a string "the quick brown fox" where the word "quick" is bold, it is represented in the non formated text (TextArea.text) as "the **quick** brown fox", now the string index of a fox is
index 16 in the formatted text but it is index 20 in the non-formatted text.

Is there an efficient way to access this?

Any idea or suggestion?